# Visual force vs lightning framework

Tags: salesforce

I need to create webpages in SalesForce, in SF we can create the webpages by using visual force(pages) and lightning framework.I am bit confused to choose one from these- I am new to salesforce.

I want to carry/transfer the data from one webpage to another page. In angular framework we can achieve it through service or providers. But in Visual force and lightning framework I am not able find suitable component for that by my own, Could anyone please help me on this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what framework you are using. 
i.e. if you are using Salesforce Classic then go with Visualforce pages or 
if you are using Lightning Experience then go with Lightning components.

Although you can use visualforce pages in lightning experience and vice versa but it is not completely recommended

You can check the trailhead modules for more details.